# Prevent Mobile on Desktop like Apple does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a question that I have searched for hours and can't find any solution to my issue.
I am trying to make it so when you resize the browser the mobile versions and break points don't show when on a desktop.
So when you're on a desktop you should be able to resize the browser to a point where you will have to scroll horizontally, rather than showing a mixture of desktop and mobile version. [apple.com](http://apple.com) does it where when you resize the browser it only goes so small and you never see the mobile version. Which you shouldn't because you're on a desktop.

Here is the site:
http://www.avrs.com/

To recreate the issue you can resize your browser and at about 1000px it breaks and is ugly. You may also say that I am doing the `display: none;` wrong which you are welcome to inform me of how to fix.

Also I am familiar with the http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities. But they didn't seem to fix this issue either.

Comment: I assume that this is the issue: http://puu.sh/ctizK/bc8fe47099.jpg ? If so, you might want to add that screenshot of mine to your initial question (while accepting my edits).

Comment: There is no way to do this using just css. What you are wanting is called browser sniffing which either relies on javascript (client side) or the user agent string (server side). You use this information to determine what device the user is using and serve different html/css based on that information.

Comment: cybermonkey... Yes that is the proper screenshot for my question.http://puu.sh/ctizK/bc8fe47099.jpg  Can you answer this, why when on Desktop and you resize it doesn't just show iPad or iPhone depending on how you resize? When I use the simulator or actual device everything works but for some reason the desktop is showing a mixture of all when you resize this seems not right.  Am I doing something wrong or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several techniques to achieve what you want. The easiest is to use CSS media-queries with specific properties.

Usually `min-width` or `max-width` are used for the CSS breakpoints to make your website mobile-friendly (*Responsive Web Design*). If you want to avoid this on desktop browsers you can use different properties with values specific to mobile devices:

- `min-device-pixel-ratio`
- `min-device-width`
- `orientation`

This source will provide more relevant information: [article on css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Another question is: Why would you want to make your website unresponsive and not user-friendly like that? In year 2014 I (and pretty much most of the users) expect websites to **adapt to the browser's window size**.

Scenario: I really like browsing websites with my browser on one half of the screen and eg. chatting with someone or watching a movie on the other half.

Consider this point. I think it's better to improve your website so it works nice in all different resolutions because you can **never assume anything about your users** and their devices (smartphones, tablets, netbooks, laptops, desktops…). Nowadays I can easily get a smartphone with higher resolution than my desktop computer, or a laptop with a touch screen.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your time.  The only reason I ask this questions is because I am using some classes to display: none; and when I resize the desktop version it doesn't work.  Am I maybe doing it wrong or why does the desktop version not show the mobile  version when I resize the browser? Rather than a mixture of both.

Comment: It's all about your media queries. If you're using Google Chrome there's a built-in tool to preview media queries and their breakpoints so you can use that to debug.
My personal advice? Go Mobile First approach: style for the smallest screens first and add media queries to target larger screens later on (`min-width`).

Answer (score 0):

The devs at Apple are using `max-device-width` (plus other `media query` rules, like `dpi`, `min/max width`, etc.) to determine if the `mobile` version will be shown. Because desktops typically have a larger `physical` screen, the `max-device-width` rules will rarely be shown on desktops (but it isn't full proof, as shown below - You'd want to look at `adaptive design` for a separation between desktops and mobile devices...)

You can test this by setting your resolution to something much smaller. Here's an example on my Macbook Pro at 720px x 450px (via Display Menu) running Chrome.

[image: Screen shot of apple.com on a desktop with a lower resolution set]

Comment: Hi and thank you for your time. I will look into this and thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  Mainly my concern with all of this is everything works great on all devices unless your on Desktop and either resize the window or zoom in it breaks at about 1024 which makes sense because its trying to show the iPad version mixed with the Desktop version and it looks horrible.  I don't think anyone but me will see this but I want it to look great no matter what the user does.  Can you think of a fix for this or what to do differently.